# Нужно найти от value2 отнять value1 и так пройтись по всем объектам массива. Затем найти среднее значение

Tags: javascript

Нужно найти от значения value2 отнять значение value1 и так пройтись по всем объектам массива. Затем найти среднее значение. Подскажите как поступить? Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
const arrow1 = [
  {property: "ghjftghjfgdjhfgj", value1: 12, value2: 15},
  {property: "tyygjtrfjrtfgjjgf", value1: 16, value2: 16},
  {property: "jfjfgjgfjfgjgfjgf", value1: 13, value2: 14},
  {property: "jfjgfjgfjgfjgfjfg", value1: 14, value2: 18},
  ];
```

Comment: Вы пробовали использовать обычный цикл?

Comment: а где ваша программа, которая это почти делает?

Comment: Подскажите с чего начать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите с чего начать

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrow1.length; i++) {
  console.log(arrow1[i].value2 - arrow1[i].value1);
}
```

Comment: @Inventor Этот код работает очень хорошо.

Comment: там среднее значение нужно, а не разность =)

Comment: @Inventor "Подскажите с чего начать"